# $E[X|X=Y]=E[Y|X=Y]=E[X]=E[Y]$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

The last piece to comprehend [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416653/conditional-expectation-exx-c-y/416680#416680) is to establish that

$$E[X|X=Y]=E[Y|X=Y].$$

I assume

$$E[X|X=Y]=E[X|\{\omega : X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\}]=E[X|A].$$

If we consider this the expectation of $X$ in $A$, then clearly the equality above holds because it must be the same as the expectation of $Y$ in $A$, as we've assumed that these two RVs are equal in $A$.

Finally, isn't it the case that $\{\omega : X(\omega)=Y(\omega)\}=\Omega,$ and therefore that $E[X|X=Y]=E[Y|X=Y]=E[X]=E[Y], $ or more generally $E[X|\Omega]=E[X]?$

So essentially the information $X=Y$ is like no information at all?

Comment: I don’t think the conditioning event makes sense. In general, you are conditioning on a set of measure 0, which is not well defined and runs afoul of paradoxes. For example, consider $W = X/Y$ and $Z = X - Y$. In the general measure-theoretic theory of conditioning, conditioning on $W = 1$ doesn’t necessarily produce the same answer as conditioning on $Z = 0$.

Comment: Which set has measure 0?  $P(A)=0$?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal then $P(A) = 0$, ignoring edge cases.

Comment: The referenced answer pulls a trick on you: at the outset it assumes something not stated in the question; namely, that "$X$ and $Y$ are exchangeable in the analysis."  This is not necessarily true, but when it is, there's nothing more to be said because it means you can switch their roles in expressions involving probability and expectation.

Comment: You say the last thing to understand in the linked answer is that $\operatorname E(X\mid X=Y) = \operatorname E(Y\mid X=Y).$ But nothing like that appears in the linked answer. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy In Gunes answer it's stated: $E[X\mid X=c-Y]=E[c-Y\mid X=c-Y].$

Comment: @user0 : So it says $\operatorname E(X\mid X+Y=c) = \operatorname E(Y\mid X+Y=c).$ Hardly an identical statement to what you wrote.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, can't we let $Z=c-Y$? Then it says $E(X|X=Z)=E(Z|X=Z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Finally, isn't it the case that  {ω:X(ω)=Y(ω)}=Ω [...] So essentially the information X=Y is like no information at all?

The random variable $Y$ doesn't have to map every element of the state space into the same real number as the random variable $X$. If it does, you're just giving an additional label, $Y$ to the random variable $X$. That gives you no information about $X$, conditioning on $X=Y$ is just conditioning on the state space as you note. But if $X$ and $Y$ are different random variables (but possibly with the same distribution), then $X=Y$ does provide information about $X$ or $Y$.

Here's a simple example. The state space $\Omega$ is $\{\omega_0, \omega_1, \omega_2 \}$ all equally likely. Specify the random variable $X$ as  $X(\omega_0) = 0$ and  $X(\omega_1) = 1$, $X(\omega_2) = 2$. Specify $Y$ as $Y(\omega_0) = 0$ and $Y(\omega_1) = 1$, $Y(\omega_2) = 3$.

Then the event $X=Y$ is the set $\{\omega_0, \omega_1\}$. Conditional on that event, the expected value of both variables is of course the same, $0.5$

Comment: Crystal clear analysis! Just to emphasize/verify: $X$ and $Y$ are drawn from the *same* state space with the *same* distribution, but have *different* assigned real numbers, so that $X=Y$ is actually a subsetting of state space. In this case, $E(X|X=Y)=E(Y|X=Y)$ remains a valid conclusion but $E(X|X=Y) \ne E(X)\ne E(Y)$. So, we can say that $X$ and $Y$ are drawn from the same distribution but are *not* exchangeable, right?  OK! That's a really important distinction!

Comment: @CloseToC.  Thank you - very nice.  I see now: the statement $\{X=Y\}$ is an observation, not an assertion.  Ie, we're observing which $\omega$ gives the same value of $X,Y$, not asserting that $\forall\ \omega,\ X(\omega)=Y(\omega).$